# How to put cookbook_file resource in for loop?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am able to add a single file from the Chef cookbook:

```rb
cookbook_file '/tmp/File1' do
  source 'default/File1'
  owner   'jenkins'
  group  'jenkins'
  mode   '0755'
end
```

How can I add `File1`, `File2`, `File3` using a `for` loop?
I went through chef docs, it is helpless and confusing.

Comment: Do you want to delete or create a file? Are you aware of the semantics of the `default/` directory below a cookbook's `files/` and `templates/` directory? If the source file is found, ignore it. If not, then remove the `default/`.

Comment: I changed the syntax. Thanks

Comment: Okay. I've removed the `action :create`. That's the default and thus redundant.

Comment: I am getting error:     Error executing action `create` on resource 'cookbook_file[/tmp/#{file}]'
. I placed three files File1, File2, File3 under files folder.

Comment: Ah sorry, in order to make use of string interpolation, double quotes have to be used. I changed my answer.

Comment: That worked StephenKing!I am on "The Eyes of the Dragon". Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111232/discussion-between-mad-engineer-and-stephenking).

Answer (score 5):

That's where you can just use Ruby code (and probably, that's the reason why chef docs don't cover that so much):

```rb
['File1', 'File2', 'File3'].each do |file|
  cookbook_file "/tmp/#{file}" do
    source "default/#{file}"
    owner 'jenkins'
    group 'jenkins'
    mode '0755'
  end
end
```